# Динамическое добавление элементов в ScrollView

Tags: java, android

Каким образом можно добавлять элементы в ScrollView программно, а не в визуальном редакторе  предварительно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Не пользуйтесь визуальным редактором - он глючный, составляйте разметку чрез `xml`
2. Чтобы добавить что-то программно в ScrollView надо сначала найти его единственного потомка, а потом уже в него добавлять вьюхи:

   ```
   ScrollView sv = ...;
   ViewGroup innerView = sv.getChildAt(0);
   //Создаём новую View
   TextView tv = new TextView(context);
   tv.setText("New View");
   innerView.addView(tv);
   ```